# array search is not working in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find picid in array but it's not working. When I echo it, nothing appears.

Here is my code

```
<?php $psql=mysql_query("select * from gallery where userId='$miid'");
$photo1 = array();

while($photo=mysql_fetch_assoc($psql)) { 
  $photo1[]=$photo;
  print_r($photo);
}

foreach($photo1 as $k => $v){
  if($v['picId']==$mipic){
    $pic="uploads/".$v['photo'];
    echo ">>>". $key=array_search($v['picId'],$photo1);
?>

 <a href="eg?next=<?php echo $photo[$k+1];?>">NEXT</a>
 <img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>" width="300px" height="300px">
 <a href="eg?previous=<?php echo $photo[$k-1];?>">PREVIOUS</a>
 <?php
  }
  }?>
```

Comment: What does your debugging infotion show? Have you checked `$k` and `$v` to make sure that they're being populated properly?

Comment: yes i have checked them its ok

Comment: The code itself has no closing `} }`, did you forget to post them here or in your script?

Comment: you got a syntax error add } before ?>

Comment: i forgot to post it over here . there is no syntax error, wait ill post it

Comment: What result do you expect? What do you want out from it?

Comment: i want to get value of next and previous picid in <a href="modules/gallery/miloader.php?next=<?php echo $photo[$k+1];?>">NEXT</a> and <a href="miloader.php?previous=<?php echo $photo[$k-1];?>">PREVIOUS</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_search is not recursive. `$v` exists in `$photo1`, while `$v['picId']` only exists in `$v`.

That makes `$key=array_search($v['picId'],$photo1)` return `false` which, when you echo it, will print as nothing.

I am not sure why you are using `array_search` at all. In order to retrieve the next and previous picId, try this:

```
<a href="modules/gallery/miloader.php?next=<?php echo $photo1[$k+1]['picId'];?>">NEXT</a>
<img src="<?php echo $pic; ?>" width="300px" height="300px">
<a href="miloader.php?previous=<?php echo $photo1[$k-1]['picId'];?>">PREVIOUS</a>
```

Beware though that one of the hrefs is `modules/gallery/miloader.php` while the other is just `miloader.php`. So unless you actually have two different miloader.php files (one in each of the directories), one of them is wrong.